# Meteor ReactiveVar unable to set value

Tags: undefined, meteor-blaze, reactive

Please, what's to be done right. I am trying to use ReactiveVar to set the value of a placeholder and I kept getting this error. It displays that ReactivarVar cannot see the set function of it.

This is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Object.change #identity (login.js:19)
    at blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3775
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3744)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3774)
    at blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2617
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2271)
    at Blaze._DOMRange.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2616)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:863)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js?hash=e15504227515793c40a6a3a8ad340399cb657500:5282)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js?hash=e15504227515793c40a6a3a8ad340399cb657500:4934)
```

This is the code

```
Template.login.onCreated(() => {
    this.identify = new ReactiveVar( "" );
});

Template.login.helpers({
    identify() {
        return Template.instance().identify.get();
      }
})

Template.login.events({
    'change #identity'(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();

        if ($(event.target).val() == "one") {
            console.log("Enter Phone Number");
            template.identify.set( "Enter Phone Number" );
        }
        if ($(event.target).val() == "two") {
            console.log("Enter Phone Number");
            template.identify.set( "Enter Age" );
        }
        if ($(event.target).val() == "one") {
            console.log("Enter Phone Number");
            template.identify.set( "Enter ID Card Number" );
        }

    }
});
```

This is my template file

```
<form class="startup" id="startup">
    <select name="identity" style="width: 310px; height: 40px;" id="identity" >
        <option selected value="select">Select an option</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="identify" id="identify" required="true" placeholder= {{identify}} >
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="true">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the actual ReactiveVar to a named variable.

For example

```
this.identify = new ReactiveVar( "state" );
```

Now you can access it in this manner.

Set variable (in event)

```
temp.identify.state.set("age", 28);
```

Get variable (in helper)

```
Template.identify.state.get("age")
```

Comment: you should precise in the event, that temp. is the second argument of the event method

Answer (score 0):

you can use this ReactiveVar wrapper .It is clean and simple to use .Please find this useful link:
https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-template-var